# Odoo. One to many search by field

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-9

I extend module for employees in odoo 9. Every employee has children. Here my models:

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    _name = 'hr.employee'
    _inherit = 'hr.employee'

    children_ids = fields.One2many('my_module', 'employee_id', string="Children")


class Child(models.Model):
    _name = 'my_module'

    name = fields.Char(required=True, string='Name')

    birthday = fields.Date(required=True, string='Birthday')

    employee_id = fields.Many2one('hr.employee', ondelete='cascade', string="Employee")
```

[image]

How can I configure search by birthday? For example, I want to set in search date of birthday(or interval of dates) and the system must show me all employees which have children with birthday from search.

[image]

Here my search view(this works by name of child):

```
<record id="view_urspectr_employee_filter" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">Employees</field>
    <field name="model">hr.employee</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="hr.view_employee_filter" />
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <search position="inside">
            <field name="children_ids"/>
        </search>
    </field>
</record>
```

I found the similar situation in module *account*(../addons/account/views/account_view.xml):

```
<record id="view_account_move_filter" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">account.move.select</field>
            <field name="model">account.move</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <search string="Search Move">
                    <field name="name" filter_domain="['|', ('name','ilike',self), ('ref','ilike',self)]" string="Move"/>
                    <field name="date"/>
```

Search by date works is good. But in this case *date* field used without relation **One2Many**.

Can you help with solution? I can't find example with search by One2Many.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here solution:

```
<record id="view_urspectr_employee_filter" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">Employees</field>
    <field name="model">hr.employee</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="hr.view_employee_filter"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <search position="inside">
            <field name="children_ids" filter_domain="[('children_ids.birthday', '=', self)]" widget="date"/>
        </search>
    </field>
</record>
```

Comment: Why should the OP try this? A good answer will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I think it is clear for visitors which working with odoo. And they can use this solution for search by date with one2many relations.

Comment: For newbies it might not be so clear. You must consider the audience. One other point, you've been going around editing code in questions and sometimes changing the nature of what the OP's have posted. *Please* do not do that.

Comment: Thank you. The example: `<field name="children_ids" filter_domain="[('children_ids.birthday, '=', self)]" />` helped me filter my many2one field by its fields.

Comment: @IstaLibera I was glad to help. Good luck ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here you try by adding the **related field of 'birthday'** in 'hr.employee' table in relation to 'children_ids', but still the problem could be that it may no search just '2015' because the data type of 'birthday' field is 'Date', not just simple string. You can give a try though.

Comment: I know. But how I can configure search by dates(if date in another model)?

Comment: I have not seen example with search by fields in another model.

Comment: If you are taking the related field in 'hr.employee' you can type in the full date ... example 2015-01-01.

Comment: Ok. I updated question. Can you provide example how to add filter by date? Now it's works only by name of child.

Comment: Try to look into the example of 'sale.order' and 'sale.order.line' models, where field product_id of sale.order.line model belongs to sale.order model as related field and used in the search view of sale.order model. Try to search for view id 'view_sales_order_filter' or view name 'sale.order.list.select'. So here you are searching for product which is there in the one2many model. In your case you need to make the 'birthday' field as related field in 'hr.employee' model.

Comment: I have no idea. In module _sale_ search(products) works by product _name_ or by product _code_. But not by date. I checked module _product_. Search by _code_ works because in search element exist next row: `<field name="name" string="Product" filter_domain="['|',('default_code','ilike',self),('name','ilike',self)]"/>` (_../addons/product/product_view.xml_).